# Windows doesn't remember installed drivers

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, drivers

Every time when I connect any USB device in my PC, for example any Pen drive or my mobile, It searches and install the drivers(basically from the internet).

Even though I have installed my phone drivers in the PC, it searches and install it from the net everytime. Also, when the same device is connected to the same Port.

What should I do in order to avoid that?

Edit: I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise(32 bit).

Comment: Please, Which specific version of windows?